# An increasing function of gamma functions?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, gamma-function, digamma-function

Let $\Gamma$ denote the gamma function and suppose $a, b > 1$. Is the function defined as,

$f_b(a) = \cfrac{\Gamma(ab)}{\Gamma(ab + 1/2)} \cfrac{\Gamma(a + 1/2)}{\Gamma(a)}$,

increasing in $a$? I was asked to prove this formally, but have run into some difficulty. Most of my attempts so far have been some variation of using the digamma function, but I haven't been able to get anywhere meaningful.

Answer (score 1):

We have that $\log\Gamma$ is a convex function by the [Bohr-Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem), and $f_b(a)$ is increasing with respect to $a$ iff 
$$\log f_b(a) = \log\frac{\Gamma(ab)}{\Gamma(a)}-\log\frac{\Gamma(ab+1/2)}{\Gamma(a+1/2)}=\int_{a}^{ab}\psi(x)-\psi(x+1/2)\,dx $$
is increasing with respect to $a$, where
$$\psi(x)-\psi(x+1/2)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{n+x+\frac{1}{2}}-\frac{1}{n+x}\right) $$
leads to:
$$ \log f_b(a) = -\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{ab}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{dx}{(n+x)(n+x+1/2)} $$
and through such a representation it is straightforward to prove that $f_b(a)$ is an increasing function.

Comment: thank you for your help! I understand all of your steps, but it is not clear to me why the above expression for $\log f_b (a)$ must be increasing in $a$. If I take the derivative with respect to $a$, it leads to (I believe) $\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{(2a^2 b - n(2n+1))(b-1)}{(a+n)(2a+2n+1)(ab+n)(2ab+2n+1)}$, but the terms in this summation will be negative for a sufficiently large value of $n$. Is there a simple way of showing that this derivative is positive? Or am I missing some more straightforward method of showing the above expression to be increasing?